# How to get Field values of a list item using CSOM Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell

How to get Field values of a list item using CSOM Powershell?

I am using below code:

```
foreach($field in $List.Fields)
{
    write-host $field
}
```

I am getting the values as output:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldDataTime
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookup
```

But I want all field values like ID, Title, Created By etc.

Comment: You need to get the fields first so: $fields = $List.Fields; $ctx.load($fields); $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Comment: @Bunzab Yes i have loaded the fields in my code. I just want the Created By and Modified By values of all the items using CSOM

Comment: In that case you need to get each item...

Comment: i am trying to get each item only but it is returning values as Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookup instead of user names

Comment: $ListItem["Editor"].LookupValue solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not retrieve any list items. This is an example of how you do it:

```
$listItems = $list.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
$ctx.load($listItems)

$ctx.executeQuery()
foreach($listItem in $listItems)
{
    Write-Host "ID - " $listItem["ID"] "Title - " $listItem["Title"]
}
```

Credits to: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/list-item-operations-using-csom-with-powershell-for-sharepoi/

Comment: $ListItemsCollection =$List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
                $ctx.load($ListItemsCollection)
                $ctx.executeQuery()
                foreach($ListItem in $ListItemsCollection)
                {

  $Author = $ListItem["Author"].LookupValue
  Write-Host $Author
                $Editor = $ListItem["Editor"].LookupValue
  Write-Host Editor
  }

Comment: Thanks @Denis. I was actually looking for  $ListItem["Editor"].LookupValue  which gives the values of user names instead of their types.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get list item values, you can use this

```
$web=Get-SPWeb "http://www.myspapp/sites/myspweb"
$list=$web.Lists["MyListNAme"]

foreach($item in $list.Items)
{
    Write-Host  $item["ID"] $item["Title"]
}
```

If you want to get column names only, you can use this

```
$web=Get-SPWeb "http://www.myspapp/sites/myspweb"
$list=$web.Lists["MyListNAme"]

foreach($field in $list.Fields)
{
    Write-Host $field
}
```

Comment: I am doing that in CSOM. The above code is for SSOM . Please assist

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the item/s first (either by CAML query or by id) and the property values are accessible via:

```
$item.FieldValues
```

So you can get the values you are after like so:

```
$item.FieldValues.Title
$item.FieldValues.ID
```